# trigger custom event without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jquery-triggerhandler

I'm triggering some DOM Events with jQuery `triggerHandler()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>stackoverflow</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com:80/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('hey', function(customEvent, originalEvent, data) {
        console.log(customEvent.type + ' ' + data.user); // hey stackoverflow

      });

      // how to this in vanilla js
      $(document).triggerHandler('hey', [{}, {
        'user': 'stackoverflow'
      }])
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I trigger this without jQuery?

**Important**: I need to know the event type and the custom data

Comment: Under the covers jQuery will be using document.addEventListener('hey', function() { ... }); where hey is click, mousedown etc. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Reading the jQuery source would show you how it's done, since jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: As far as i remember, jquery combines `.dispatchEvent` and `.fireEvent` for triggerHandler. You can easily write a function to try one or the other. dispatch event will work on most browsers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want an **exact** replication of jQuery's behaviour, you're probably best off digging through the [`jQuery source code`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery).

If you just want to do normal event dispatching and listening, see [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) for how to dispatch an event with custom data and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for how to listen to it.

Your example would probably look something like

```
document.addEventListener('hey', function(customEvent)
{
    console.log(customEvent.type + ' ' + customEvent.detail.user); // hey stackoverflow
});
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('hey', {'detail': {'user': 'stackoverflow'}}));
```

Comment: `CustomEvent` constructor has no support in IE.

Comment: @Johnston But it looks like there's a [polyfill for it](https://github.com/krambuhl/custom-event-polyfill/blob/master/custom-event-polyfill.js).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Custom Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) and dispatch them on element you want.